# how to import h5py on datalab?

Tags: gcloud, h5py, google-cloud-datalab

Does anybody know how to install h5py on datalab? pip install h5py doesn't work. apt-get install python-h5py is working in the shell but it doesn't recognize the package in datalab notebook!

Thnaks

Answer (score 2):

It is true that `!pip install h5py` wil allow you to install the library but unfortunately, even after a successful installation, the import will fail: [image]

The issue is rooted on an ongoing python-future issue (["surrogateescape handler broken when encountering UnicodeEncodeError"](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/issues/256)) that is experienced in datalab because the underlying OS uses an 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' file system encoding.

As a hacky workaround, you may remove line 60 from h5py's `__init__.py` by running the following command from within a notebook cell:

```
!sed -i.bak '/run_tests/d' /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py
```

Comment: If the OP doesn't need the latest version, `pip install -U h5py==2.6` is probably a cleaner solution, until that issue is fixed. Make sure no dependencies are changed though.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you run it using bash syntax: `!pip install h5py` in any notebook cell.